# Ionic2-calendar, customize styles?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Github repository of calendar: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar

Using the ionic2-calendar directive how to customize event colors on the calendar? Is there any way to do that? Also how to use my own event-list template instead of native one?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is an answer to that in docs, this is for example template of event details at the bottom of calendar.

```
<template #template let-showEventDetail="showEventDetail" let-selectedDate="selectedDate" let-noEventsLabel="noEventsLabel">
  ... 
  </template>

  <calendar ... [monthviewEventDetailTemplate]="template"></calendar>
```